# Plot residual error graph in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I have a multiple linear regression model with one output value and two input values.

```
z=Ax+By+C
```

I would like to plot a graph of residual errors vs instances. Is there any standard tool which I can use. I have the data and to use Openoffice calc, I can calculate SLOPE and INTERCEPT from inbuilt functions but they can be used for a simple linear regression only. HOw can I use 
calc. here.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your data, your fitted regression surface is a plane, therefore your residuals are naturally visualised as a perpendicular height field above or below the `(x,y)` coordinate of each observation point (unless this was obtained using orthogonal distance regression of course but you don't specify this). Thus you really need a surface plot and a software package that will allow you to produce one.

Alternatively, if your data points are arranged as a mesh, you could produce a series of simply regression plots by effectively fixing each of the `x` (or `y`) values in your set and producing a residual plot for **each** `x` value. Effectively you are splitting your planar mesh residual plot into a series of parallel lines that can be displayed with your tool.

You do not specify whether you have meshed data or if this is acceptable, so as a suggestion I would take a look at **Octave** as a display tool. This has the capability of producing 3D surface plots and meshes which is really what you need to effectively display a residual surface obtained from this type of analysis. If you have not used Octave before you will have a bit of a learning curve but it is worth a try unless you get an answer that suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.miabella-llc.com/demo.html) is a web-based, interactive tool for [plotting regression results in three dimensions](http://www.miabella-llc.com/demo.html).

This 3-D plot works with one dependent variable and two explanatory variables. You can also set the intercept to zero -- i.e., remove the intercept from the regression equation.

The graphics require a WebGL-capable browser, and the most recent versions of all major desktop browsers support WebGL.

[image]